# How to find the number of pixels that vary between two images

Tags: image-processing

Given two $n \times m$ images, what's the fastest way to count the number of pixels that are different between the two images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For single channel images like

```
image1 = Image[ {{0, 50, 100, 150, 255}, {0, 50, 100, 150, 200}}, "Byte"]
image2 = Image[ {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 50, 100, 150, 200}}, "Byte"]
```

you can get `5` using

```
Total[Unitize[Subtract @@ (ImageData /@ {image1, image2})], 2]
```

or

```
Total[Unitize@ImageData@ImageDifference[image1, image2], 2]
```

In general, you can use

```
ClearAll[difCount]
difCount = If[ImageChannels[#] === 1, 
    Total[Unitize @ ImageData @ ImageDifference @ ##, 2], 
    Total[Unitize[Apply[Times, ImageData @ ImageDifference @ ##, {2}]], 2]] &;

difCount[image1, image2]
```

> 5

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach that avoids [`ImageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageData):

```
image1 = Image[RandomInteger[256, {3000, 3000}]];
image2 = Image[RandomInteger[256, {3000, 3000}]];

ImageMeasurements[
    Binarize[
        ImageDifference[image1, image2],
        0
    ],
    "Total"
]
% //Rationalize
```

> 8.96489*10^6
>
> 8964885

And a timing comparison:

```
ImageMeasurements[
    Binarize[
        ImageDifference[image1, image2],
        0
    ],
    "Total"
] //Rationalize //AbsoluteTiming

Total[Unitize @ ImageData @ ImageDifference[image1, image2], 2] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.045073, 8964885}
>
> {0.073831, 8964885}

About 40% faster.